# Typescript toString function does not work as expected

Tags: javascript

I have tried the following code snippet in TypeScript.

```js
class MyArray extends Array{
    toString(){
        return '[PRIVATE]';
    }
}
let a = new MyArray(1,2,3,4,5);
console.log(`${a}`);
```

the expected output is the string called as [PRIVATE] but the actual output is the array of 1,2,3,4,5. can anyone explain what happens here?

Comment: I've replaced the code block in your code with a code snippet (just adding a missing `}`). As you can see, it outputs the expected string. It also does that [on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBBATss9oFMAeAXTAdgCYwprwDeAUNLdLgPYDKuyAlgQOYAUAlNXUHRkmXAFdkBaAHIA2gAUASgEkAaogAqAUQC60gNw06AXyqmQo6GGgBeaAUwB3OElTpuARgA0AJi8BmLwAWLwBWXkNgBgIIBgsAOhAGHgADABIKMGMUiKA), and moreover, it *should* do that. :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Note that we know the output will reliably be the string `"[PRIVATE]"` because you're forcing the conversion of the array to string via an untagged template literal. But if you did `console.log(a);`, you'd almost certainly see a representation of the array, not the string `"[PRIVATE]"`, because most consoles don't use simple conversion-to-string for output, they try to provide a useful representation of what was logged (in this case, the array's entries). But with ```console.log(`${a}`)``` as in your question, it's the string from `toString` that's logged.

Comment: I tried this code with webstorm where it does not display expected output. can you explain why it happens?

Comment: If you're really doing ```console.log(`${a}`)``` and not `console.log(a)`, all due respect I can't see Webstorm this wrong. All due respect, I think you must be doing `console.log(a)` instead. See my [second comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187328/typescript-tostring-function-does-not-work-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment108244089_61187328) for details.